# Deciding on a font, and determining the proper notation

Tags: x11, fonts

I have an X11 program that allows you to set a font.  It apparently accepts the 'standard' [X Logical Font Description](http://www.xfree86.org/current/fonts5.html).  This notation is fairly obscure, and while the document I linked to mentions it, it doesn't actually describe the syntax.  Is there some kind of font picking tool that will provide a list of valid fonts, and allow me to pick a font from the list, and specify the sizes and such, then print out this notation?

> X Logical Font Description
>
> X11 core font instances are usually specified using a notation known
>   as the X Logical Font Description (XLFD). An XLFD starts with a dash
>   `-', and consists of fourteen fields separated by dashes, for example:
>
> -adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--12-120-75-75-m-70-iso8859-1

Comment: The XLFD specification can be found at http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/ along with a more up-to-date version of that old XFree86 doc you linked to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`xfontsel` lets you browse through the available X11 fonts and provides rendered previews so you can see what they actually look like.  It's fairly plain-looking and basic but it is provided with most Xorg installations by default.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `xlsfonts`, it can be used in scripts because it produces plain text output.